# How do I remove this folder from the Windows Explorer navigation bar?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, files-folders

Consider:

[image]

I want to remove this "games" folder from the Navigation Bar, but I can't come up with anything to do. I have tried going through properties and using right click, but I couldn't remove it.

It is Windows 11.

Comment: You should be able to remove the shortcut by removing the software responsible for the folder, which appears, to be Mega.

Comment: Do you have a piece of software that places these shortcuts there? Or is that the Recent folders you've accessed? In File Explorer open the View tab and open Options and adjust settings in the Privacy group and see if this resolves that issue. However, I'm more familiar with the Recent/Frequent items being below the Pinned items, which makes me wonder if another piece of software has added those folders to the top. A screenshot showing more of the left side of your File Explorer window may help us better understand the source of those items.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove this in MEGAsync settings, Syncs tab, check
"Don't show icons on the left pane of Windows Explorer":

[image]

If the option has disappeared, then this `.reg` file might fix it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CAEB938D-211C-4C45-B35D-AE53F1C77167}]
@="MEGAsync"
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000000
```

Source :
[How to Remove MEGA in Navigation Pane](https://www.tenforums.com/customization/84475-how-remove-mega-navigation-pane.html).